# How to define an constructor argument accessible from Xaml

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

Xamarin's `ListView` defines a 1-argument constructor as follows:

```
public ListView([Parameter("CachingStrategy")] ListViewCachingStrategy cachingStrategy)
```

As a result, `CachingStrategy` can be used in Xaml:

```
<ListView CachingStrategy="RecycleElement" .../>
```

I'm wondering how I can do the same thing.  The following code, as is, does not compile because `ParameterAttribute` is internal to Xamarin.Forms:

```
public ItemListControl([Parameter("IsReadOnly")] bool isReadOnly)
```

I copied class `ParameterAttribute` from Xamarin.Forms, and the above compiled, but had no effect on Xaml processing.  Here is the class, for reference:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Parameter)]
internal sealed class ParameterAttribute : Attribute
{
    public ParameterAttribute(string name)
    {
        Name = name;
    }

    public string Name { get; }
}
```

Is there anything I'm missing?

Comment: It seems there is a hack option available as the XAMLC task as it uses only `FullName` match with type name. I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To make things simpler, I would recommend creating a [`BindableProperty`](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/xaml/bindable-properties/#Creating_and_Consuming_a_Bindable_Property) for `IsReadOnly`. But you can always use [`x:Arguments`](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/xaml/passing-arguments/#Passing_Constructor_Arguments) to pass in parameters to constructor:

```
<local:ItemListControl ...>
    <x:Arguments>
        <x:Boolean>true</x:Boolean>
    </x:Arguments>
</local:ItemListControl>
```

**EDIT - 1**

There is one hack that you can use - (I wouldn't recommend as this could [change anytime with an update](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/blob/master/Xamarin.Forms.Build.Tasks/CreateObjectVisitor.cs#L110) in XAMLC compilation) - but you can make sure to keep the namespace same as the one used internally while defining the parameter attribute.

```
namespace Xamarin.Forms
{
    [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Parameter)]
    internal sealed class ParameterAttribute : Attribute
    {
        public ParameterAttribute(string name)
        {
            Name = name;
        }

        public string Name { get; }
    }
}
```

And XAML usage would look like:

```
<local:ItemListControl IsReadOnly="true" .. />
```

**EDIT - 2**
This hack only seems to work if [XAMLCompilation](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/xaml/xamlc/) is applied to host control/page.

Comment: Yeah, I'm aware of the 2 options you listed before EDIT.  The property doesn't even have to be bindable.  But I do want it in constructor, and I want simpler syntax in Xaml.  Perfectionism. :-)

You hack suggestion is... cool.  I wouldn't believe they did it this way if I didn't see it with my own eyes.  Really bad design.  Not sure if I'll use it, but thanks, and this totally answers the question!

Comment: Well I guess, if the build-task changes in future, you can register your own that will map the constructor parameters for you. I personally wouldn't go down this path as it is too hackish in my opinion, unless `Xamarin.Forms` dev team decides to make that attribute public.